Python Pandas Dataframe: Make Rows from Multiple Column Into Multiple Column
I have dataframe like this:



Product
Colour
Grade
Price
Size




Apple
Yellow
A
1000
3


Apple
Green
B
500
4


Banana
Yellow
B
2000
5


Banana
Green
A
3000
6



I want to convert the dataframe to:



Product
Price_Yellow_A
Size_Yellow_A
Price_Yellow_B
Size_Yellow_B
Price_Green_A
Size_Green_A
Price_Green_B
Size_Green_B




Apple
1000
3
0
0
0
0
500
4


Banana
0
0
2000
5
3000
6
0
0



How to do this?

You can use pd.pivot() to achieve this, with some other intermediary steps.
First create a column of the combined Colour and Grade like this:
df['Combined'] = df['Colour'] + '_' + df['Grade']

0    Yellow_A
1     Green_B
2    Yellow_B
3     Green_A
Name: Combined, dtype: object

Then pivot() the dataframe, keeping Product as your index, using the new Combined column as columns and the Price and Size columns as values.  I added .fillna(0) to put 0s in the blanks. Like this:
new_df = df.pivot(index='Product', columns=['Combined'], values=['Price', 'Size']).fillna(0)

           Price                              Size                          
Combined Green_A Green_B Yellow_A Yellow_B Green_A Green_B Yellow_A Yellow_B
Product                                                                     
Apple        0.0   500.0   1000.0      0.0     0.0     4.0      3.0      0.0
Banana    3000.0     0.0      0.0   2000.0     6.0     0.0      0.0      5.0

This returns the desired table, but with mutli-level columns, so we can use a bit of list comprehension to rename the columns to the desired column names, like this:
new_df.columns = [col[0]+'_'+col[1] for col in new_df.columns]

         Price_Green_A  Price_Green_B  Price_Yellow_A  Price_Yellow_B  Size_Green_A  Size_Green_B  Size_Yellow_A  Size_Yellow_B
Product                                                                                                                        
Apple              0.0          500.0          1000.0             0.0           0.0           4.0            3.0            0.0
Banana          3000.0            0.0             0.0          2000.0           6.0           0.0            0.0            5.0

Full code:
df['Combined'] = df['Colour'] + '_' + df['Grade']
new_df = df.pivot(index='Product', columns=['Combined'], values=['Price', 'Size']).fillna(0)
new_df.columns = [col[0]+'_'+col[1] for col in new_df.columns]

